# Squid - Can I purge cache objects in squid-cache using url?

Tags: caching, object, squid, purge

I am new to squid-cache. I am looking for purging objects using http url.

```
http://$cacheuser$:$cachepassword$@$cache$:8081/CE/Delete/<protocol>/<machine-name>/<folder>/<file>
```

Will this work properly. Does squid support this kind of purge through url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hosted a cgi script in cache machine which listens for http request and executes squidclient.

```
use CGI qw(:standard); 

$urltopurge=param("url"); 

print $urltopurge;

print header(); 

print "Trying to purge <b>$urltopurge</b><P>"; 

print "sending command <B>squidclient -v -m PURGE -h 172.24.133.181 -p 8081 $urltopurge</b> to proxy server<P><HR><b>Server Response:</b><P>"; 

$result = system ("C:\\squid\\bin\\squidclient.exe -v -m PURGE -p 8081 $urltopurge"); 

print $result;

print "<hr>"; 

print "purger.cgi - Praveen";
```